# Handling two observables in canDeactivate

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

In my canDeactivate() route guard, I am calling a modal that has two buttons: ok and cancel. I want to return true if the ok button gets clicked so that the user can continue leaving the page, and return false if the cancel button gets clicked. Here is my current code:

```
canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    let can =  component.canDeactivate();
    //let result = new Observable<boolean>();
    let okResult = new Observable<boolean>();
    let cancelResult = new Observable<boolean>();

    if (!can) {
      component.myChangesModal.show('Warning', 'You are about to leave this page with unsaved changes.');

      okResult = component.myChangesModal.okEvent.map(() => true);
      //okResult.subscribe();

      cancelResult = component.myChangesModal.cancelEvent.map(() => false);
      //cancelResult.subscribe();
      console.log(okResult);
      console.log(cancelResult);

      const observablesArray = [okResult, cancelResult];

      let result = Observable.combineLatest.apply(this, observablesArray).take(1);
      result.subscribe();

      return result;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Initially when testing this out, I only had a single observable for checking when the ok button gets called, and would then subscribe to that, and return the result. This worked, however it only worked for one button and whenever clicking on the cancel button this broke everything. Here is what I had initially that worked perfectly for only one button.

```
canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    let can =  component.canDeactivate();
    let result = new Observable<boolean>();

    if (!can) {
      component.myChangesModal.show('Warning', 'You are about to leave this page with unsaved changes.');

      result = component.myChangesModal.okEvent.map(() => true);
      result.subscribe();

      return result;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to get my canDeactivate modal to work with more than one observable, and what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CombineLatest will wait til both observables emit a value.  That never happens for your case.  You want `Observable.merge` instead.

```
return okResult.merge(cancelResult).take(1)
```

or

```
return Observable.merge(okResult, cancelResult).take(1)
```

Comment: `merge` will work here, there is also `Observable.race` that behaves very similar in this case.